# MVC / Repository Pattern - Architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, architecture, repository-pattern

I have a project in which I am using NHibernate and ASP.Net MVC. The application is intended to allow users to track certain data and then produce views of statistics based upon the data entered. The structure of my application thus far looks something like this:

**NHibernate Layer:** Contains `Repository<T>` and `UnitOfWork` classes, as well as entity mapping definitions.

**Core/Service Layer**: Contains generic `EntityService` class. At the moment, this simply defines transaction scope via `IUnitOfWork` and interfaces with `IRepository` to provide higher-level data access services.

**Presentation Layer (MVC Application)**: Not yet implemented, but contains the usual stuff plus dependency injection.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is it poor design to allow my MVC application to handle dependency injection for ALL layers? For example, as well as dependency injection of `EntityService` instances into controllers, it will handle the dependency injection of `IRepository` into the `EntityService` classes. Should the service layer handle this itself, even though this would mean performing dependency injection in two distinct places?
2. Where should I produce my statistics? This business logic doesn't seem to belong in my service layer, which, at present, only contains entity type definitions and an interface for modifying and accessing entity properties. I have a few thoughts on this, but I'm not sure which I like best:

   - Keep my service layer as is and create a separate Statistics project - this is completely independent of the entity types for which it will be used, meaning my MVC controllers will have to pass raw numerical information between my business entities and my (presumably static) statistics classes. This is quite a neat separation but potentially means a lot of business logic still remaining in the presentation layer.
   - Create a Statistics project; however, create a tight coupling between the classes in this project and my business entities. For example, instead of passing a `Reading` object's *values* into a method, I will pass the entire object (or define them as extension methods). This will shift business logic out of my MVC app but the tight coupling seems a bit messy.
   - Keep all of my business logic inside my service layer. Define strongly-typed subclasses of `EntityService`, so my services contain both entity-specific business methods and data storage methods, while keeping the entity classes themselves as pure data containers. Create a separate Statistics project for any generic statistical processing and call its methods via my derived service classes. My service classes effectively merge business functions with the storage functionality provided created by `IRepository<T>`.

I am erring toward the third option but does anyone have any thoughts? Alternative suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preliminary observation:

I like the way in which you described your project, I just didn't get why your **Data Access Layer** (DAL) is called NHibernate Layer: it is odd with all the rest in which you didn't use technology name to describe a logical layer (correctly). So I suggest you to rename it DAL, and use it to abstract your app from NHibernate.

My opinions about your questions:

1. Absolutely no. It is good to apply Dependency Injection to All Layers. A couple or reasons for which it is good:

   1.1 **Testing**: you can mock DAL interfaces and do unit test Service Layer w/o DAL using another DI config file. In the same way you can mock Service for Web Controllers layer and so on.

   1.2 **Different DAL implementations**: suppose you need different DAL implementation (NOSQL, SQL or LINQ instead of NHibernate, etc..) technologies for different deployment of you project or to scale in the future. You can do that easily maintaining different DI config files.
2. You can have the same layer deployed in different projects. In the same way you can have a project containing different layers. I think their relation is orthogonal: project is describing a physical (development time and run time) implementation. Layers are logical. So initially I would keep it simple with the third option. 
   I just don't understand why you saying the following regarding this option:

> Create a separate Statistics project for any generic statistical
>   processing and call its methods via my derived service classes. My
>   service classes effectively merge business functions with the storage
>   functionality provided created by IRepository.

I see Statistics as one or more services so you can implement it as namespace with classes inside your Service Layer. And, as any other service, you can inject DAL Repository classes. And, as any other Service/DAL, the Model classes can be shared between different Services and DAL classes.

---

`StatsService.AverageReadingFor(Person p, DateTime start, DateTime end)` sounds good.

There are several implementation options:

1. Using underlying repository features (for example: SQL avg function)
2. Using [**Observer Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) which is implementable also using Dependency Injection
3. Using Aspect Oriented Programming. See that [Spring.Net chapter](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html) as an example.

If you have more than one Service Layer instance (more than one server) than 2 and 3 must be adapted for out of process communication using a messaging system.

Comment: To try and elaborate a little on my second question - I have a bunch of EntityService classes, for example PersonService and ReadingService, which expose my repositories to my app. My issue is now how best to implement classes to produce various statistics on `Person.IList<Reading> Readings` - for example, would it be more appropriate to have (as a simple example) `StatsService.AverageReadingFor(Person p, DateTime start, DateTime end)` in my service layer, or just do `Person.Readings.Where(e => e.DateRecorded ... )` inside my controller and average them there?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions by the way, I have implemented my dependency injection and renamed my NHibernate layer to DataAccess.

Comment: Are the statistics part of business logic (and functional requirements) or are you using it for application monitoring purpose?

Comment: They're functional requirements - production of real-time statistical data will be a core part of the application's functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at building a statistics service into my service layer, which is tightly-coupled with my entity classes.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I have added a separate answer that details a little more about what I have decided to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update - Regarding my second question, I have decided to define an `IStatsService<T>` which expects an `IEntityService<T>` to be passed into its constructor. I'll use this for generic statistical processing of business entities and create further interfaces that implement `IStatsService<T>` where I need more type-specific information.

Hopefully this will help someone who has been scratching their head about a similar problem!